# iterparse fails to parse a field, while other similar ones are fine

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, iterparse

I use Python's `iterparse` to parse the XML result of a nessus scan (.nessus file). The parsing fails on unexpected records, wile similar ones have been parsed correctly.

The general structure of the XML file is a lot of records like the one below:

```
<ReportHost>
  <ReportItem>
    <foo>9.3</foo>
    <bar>hello</bar>
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem>
     <foo>10.0</foo>
     <bar>world</bar>
</ReportHost>
<ReportHost>
   ...
</ReportHost>
```

In other words a lot of hosts (`ReportHost`) with a lot of items to report (`ReportItem`), and the latter having several characteristics (`foo`, `bar`). I will be looking at generating one line per item, with its characteristics.

The parsing fails in the middle of the file at a simple line (`foo` in that case being `cvss_base_score`)

```
<cvss_base_score>9.3</cvss_base_score>
```

while ~200 similar lines have been parsed without problems.

The relevant piece of code is below -- it sets context markers (`inReportHost` and `inReportEvent` which tell me where in the stricture of the XML file I am in, and either assign or print a value, depending on the context)

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
inReportHost = False
inReportItem = False

for event, elem in ET.iterparse("test2.nessus", events=("start", "end")):
    if event == 'start' and elem.tag == "ReportHost":
        inReportHost = True
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag == "ReportHost":
        inReportHost = False
        elem.clear()
    if inReportHost:
        if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'ReportItem':
            inReportItem = True
            cvss = ''
        if event == 'start' and inReportItem:
            if event == 'start' and elem.tag == 'cvss_base_score':
                cvss = elem.text
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == 'ReportItem':
            print cvss
            inReportItem = False
```

`cvss` sometimes has the None value (after the `cvss = elem.text` assignment), even though identical entries have been parsed properely earlier in the file.

If I add below the assignement something along the lines of

```
if cvss is None: cvss = "0"
```

then the parsing of many further `cvss` assign their proper values (and some other are None).

When taking the `<ReportHost>...</reportHost>` which causes the wrong parsing and running it through the program - it works fine (ie. `cvss` is assigned `9.3` as expected).

I am lost at where I make a mistake in my code since, withing a large set of similar records, some apre processed correctly and some - not (some of the records are identical, and still are processed differently). I also cannot find anything particular about the records that fail - identical ones earlier and later are fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [iterparse() docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#functions):

> Note: iterparse() only guarantees that it has seen the “>” character
>   of a starting tag when it emits a “start” event, so the attributes are
>   defined, but the contents of the text and tail attributes are
>   undefined at that point. The same applies to the element children;
>   they may or may not be present. If you need a fully populated element,
>   look for “end” events instead.

Drop `inReport*` variables and process ReportHost only on "end" events when it fully parsed. Use ElementTree API to get necessary info such as `cvss_base_score` from current ReportHost element.

To preserve memory, do:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

def getelements(filename_or_file, tag):
    context = iter(etree.iterparse(filename_or_file, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context) # get root element
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == tag:
            yield elem
            root.clear() # preserve memory

for host in getelements("test2.nessus", "ReportHost"):
    for cvss_el in host.iter("cvss_base_score"):
        print(cvss_el.text)
```

Comment: Thanks you - this was really helpful. I have updated the example of XML file to better reflect the reality (several items per host). I will try to build my code around your idea, with probably two loops (one for the hosts, then for the items within the host), but I will first have to clearly understand how the iteration works.

Comment: @WoJ: `.iter()` method is recursive i.e., it doesn't matter how many `ReportItem` there are; all `cvss_base_score` will be found whatever `ReportItem` they belong (or even if `cvss_base_score` element is outside of any `ReportItem`).

Comment: @j-f-sebastian: I understand, but I also need to know which `ReportItem` they belong to. I am trying to output lines of the form (taking the example XML) `host1,foo="9.3",bar="hello"` and `host2,foo="10.0",bar="world"`. It is now clear for me (from your example) how to extract fields, but I need to keep them in context (link them to the item they belong to)