# best practices for iterparse usage while keeping the context?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, iterparse

Following [a question I asked on iterparse general usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670792/iterparse-fails-to-parse-a-field-while-other-similar-ones-are-fine) (and its answer by [J F Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian)) I will reorganise my code to parse nessus XML result files. Quoting from the earlier question, the file structure is

```
<ReportHost host="host1">
  <ReportItem id="100">
    <foo>9.3</foo>
    <bar>hello</bar>
  </ReportItem>
  <ReportItem id="200">
     <foo>10.0</foo>
     <bar>world</bar>
</ReportHost>
<ReportHost host="host2">
   ...
</ReportHost>
```

In other words a lot of hosts (`ReportHost`) with a lot of items to report (`ReportItem`), and the latter having several characteristics (`foo`, `bar`). I will be looking at generating one line per item, with its characteristics:

```
host1,id="100",foo="9.3",bar="hello"
host1,id="200"foo="10.0",bar="world"
host2,...
```

I understand how to extract given fileds from the XML file (this is in essence the answer to my previous question). I need to keep these extracted fields in context (= I need to know which `ReportHost` and `ReportItem` they relate to).
My idea was to use a marker, a variable which would tell me whether I am in a `ReportHost` or `ReportItem` block and decide from there (`if inReportHost: ...`) - I have a fear that this is not the proper way to navigate XML with iterparse, though.

Is there a "best practices" document which would refer to that?

**EDIT**: improved example following comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over items via `etree.iterparse()` and detecting them via `end`, you'll have to preserve the intermediate elements in order to display, to which host they belong to.

In your example, the first two parsed elements are `<ReportItem id="100">` and `<ReportItem id="200">`. `<ReportHost host="host1">` comes next. That should be the point where you concatenate the preserved intermediate information and print the `ReportHost` details at once.

Another way would be parsing the document twice, first time for collecting the `ReportHost` data, second time - to print the each `ReportItem` details.

You can profile these methods to find which one suits you best.

Comment: OK, this is basically what I intended to do (a purely linear analysis of the events). Thanks!